# WSO2 AIPM api-import-export-2.6.0-v14.war version.issue

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-data-services-server

I have placed the  api-import-export-2.6.0-v14.war file in the /repository/deployment/server/webapps folder. and started my wso 2.6.0 server and got the following issue please help.

ERROR - ContainerBase ContainerBase.addChild: start:
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/api-import-export-2.6.0-v14]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:1015)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:991)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.internal.CarbonTomcat.addWebApp(CarbonTomcat.java:298)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.internal.CarbonTomcat.addWebApp(CarbonTomcat.java:206)
        at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TomcatGenericWebappsDeployer.handleWebappDeployment(TomcatGenericWebappsDeployer.java:255)
        at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TomcatGenericWebappsDeployer.handleWarWebappDeployment(TomcatGenericWebappsDeployer.java:206)
        at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TomcatGenericWebappsDeployer.handleHotDeployment(TomcatGenericWebappsDeployer.java:175)
        at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TomcatGenericWebappsDeployer.deploy(TomcatGenericWebappsDeployer.java:140)
        at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.AbstractWebappDeployer.deployThisWebApp(AbstractWebappDeployer.java:224)
        at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.AbstractWebappDeployer.deploy(AbstractWebappDeployer.java:114)
        at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.deployer.WebappDeployer.deploy(WebappDeployer.java:42)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.DeploymentFileData.deploy(DeploymentFileData.java:136)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.doDeploy(DeploymentEngine.java:807)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.WSInfoList.update(WSInfoList.java:144)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.update(RepositoryListener.java:377)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.checkServices(RepositoryListener.java:254)
        at org.apache.synapse.Axis2SynapseController.deployMediatorExtensions(Axis2SynapseController.java:746)
        at org.apache.synapse.Axis2SynapseController.createSynapseEnvironment(Axis2SynapseController.java:388)
        at org.apache.synapse.ServerManager.start(ServerManager.java:183)
        at org.wso2.carbon.mediation.initializer.ServiceBusInitializer.initESB(ServiceBusInitializer.java:468)
        at org.wso2.carbon.mediation.initializer.ServiceBusInitializer.activate(ServiceBusInitializer.java:206)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:107)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:861)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:819)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:771)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:214)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:433)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:451)
        at org.wso2.carbon.inbound.endpoint.persistence.service.InboundEndpointPersistenceServiceDSComponent.activate(InboundEndpointPersistenceServiceDSComponent.java:49)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:107)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:861)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:819)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:771)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:214)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:433)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:451)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.initializeCarbon(CarbonServerManager.java:515)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.removePendingItem(CarbonServerManager.java:291)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.PreAxis2ConfigItemListener.bundleChanged(PreAxis2ConfigItemListener.java:118)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:847)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [WebappLoader[/api-import-export-2.6.0-v14]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5502)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
        ... 71 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Undefined environment: CXF3
        at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.loader.CarbonWebappLoader.startInternal(CarbonWebappLoader.java:47)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
        ... 73 more
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Undefined environment: CXF3
        at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.loader.ClassloadingContextBuilder.buildClassloadingContext(ClassloadingContextBuilder.java:172)
        at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.loader.CarbonWebappLoader.startInternal(CarbonWebappLoader.java:45)
        ... 74 more
[2020-06-19 20:44:03,931] ERROR - CarbonTomcat Webapp StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/api-import-export-2.6.0-v14] failed to deploy
[2020-06-19 20:44:03,933] ERROR - TomcatGenericWebappsDeployer Error while deploying webapp: StandardContext[api-import-export-2.6.0-v14.war].File[C:\PROGRA~1\WSO2\APIMAN~1\26581D~1.0\bin..\repository\deployment\server\webapps\api-import-export-2.6.0-v14.war]
org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.CarbonTomcatException: Webapp failed to deploy
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.internal.CarbonTomcat.addWebApp(CarbonTomcat.java:310)

Comment: Are you using the latest WUM updated APIM 2.6.0 pack?

Comment: If not, using the latest APIM 2.6.0 pack will solve your issue, as this shows an incompatibility issue in the code.

Comment: But i think for wum we need to subscirbe to it .is there any work around for this without subscribing because i have tried with api-import-export-2.5.1-v1 and it worked but when i use api-import-export-2.6.0-v14 its showing this error . sorry if i am wrong i am new to this wso2 aipm and  i am confused a little bit

Comment: The thing is, with api-import-export-2.6.0-v14, some fixes have been fixed which also affects the WSO2 APIM 2.6.0 and in order to get those fixes you have to use the latest WUM updated WSO2 APIM 2.6.0 pack. As a workaround, you can use https://docs.wso2.com/download/attachments/103334679/api-import-export-2.6.0-v2.war?api=v2 version of the web app.

Comment: More details can be found at https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Initializing+projects+using+the+CLI+Tool